# MySQL Script not entering correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL and PHP script to enter a row when it doesn't exist.

```
INSERT INTO `tblPlayerAchievements` (HS_ID, AchievementID, AchievementProgress) 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ".$userData['HS_ID'].", ".$achievementID.", 0) AS tmp 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `tblPlayerAchievements` 
WHERE HS_ID=".$userData['HS_ID']." AND AchievementID=".$achievementID.") 
LIMIT 1
```

This works perfectly until both $userData['HS_ID'] and $achievementID are the same value and then it skips that one. How do I fix this?

Comment: [This sounds like a very convoluted way of doing something very simple.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I need to enter the row if it doesn't exist. How else do I do it, if not this way?

Comment: What do you need to do if it *does* exist?

Comment: Once its entered into the database I can then use that info. I'm storing achievement progress in the database. I can then reload that achievement progress later down the line.

Comment: why don't u check if the record doesn't exist first before insert it?

Comment: Because that two queries to the database rather than one. Isn't one query more efficient than two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't bothered answering the question about what happens if the row exists, I'm going to assume that you want the `INSERT` to fail. In that case, all you need to do is create a `UNIQUE` index on `(HS_ID, AchievementID)`. I also recommend that you set a default value of `0` on `AchievementProgress` so that your query only needs to specify the IDs to create the row.

Comment: I did answer why I needed it inserted. So I could recall the information later. -- EDIT Oh sorry I misread you're comment. Yeah I need it to fail if it does exist.

Comment: HS_ID and AchievementID are concatenated primary key. It works on ALL other entries until HS_ID and AchievementID are the same value. That insert then fails.

Comment: So then... what exactly do you want the query to do?

Comment: I want it to insert the query if it does not exist. If it does exist, it should fail. I already have HS_ID and achievementID as concatenated primary keys. I don't know why its skipping when HS_ID and AchievementID are the same value.

Comment: I don't understand why you're doing that huge mass of a query then. An `INSERT` will fail if the fields in a unique key have values that already exist in the table.